# Reroute on specific state of Redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm using React.js with Redux, React-Router and React-Router-Redux.

I would like to to manually reroute (or call an action) when the store reaches a specific state. How do I listen if the store has a specific state? Where do I reroute or call the action?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? I'm getting a sense of there being an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem here, and you might get a better answer with more context. In general, you shouldn't need to change the state based on the state.

Comment: Think of the following scenario. A part of the state is loaded asynchronously from some databases (more than one). When database transactions are finished I want to call an action and inside that action alter the route. Each end of a database transaction is noted in the store state.

Comment: So essentially, how can you change the route once a series of async requests have completed? Not when there are properties on the store that are equal to some specific known values?

Comment: Yes, but as I have multiple databases I have to store somewhere which database were already initialized (and only reroute when all are ready). And where do I store that ... in a Redux store :-)

Comment: But the more I think about it you and Henrik are right. Maybe those initialization stuff doesn't fit into the store. I will handle it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If these calls are made async then using an async action creator and the promise would handle this quite well.

```
// Action creator
function doTheStuff(someData, router) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(somePendingAction());
        return myRequestLib.post('/the-endpoint/', someData)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.isTransactionDone) {
                    dispatch(transactionDoneAction(response));
                    router.transitionTo('/theUrl');
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I wouldn't put this into the store since I believe the stores only job is to contain/handle the data.

Answer (score 0):

To initiate a page change when a series of other actions have completed and been persisted to the store, dispatch the following `redux-thunk`. The key here is that you have a chain of thunks which return promises, and then once they all complete, you can update the router with another action.

In a component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { doStuff, doMoreStuff } from './actions';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  onClick = e => {
    const { doStuff, doMoreStuff, push } = this.props; // these are already wrapped by dispatch because we use connect
    ...
    doStuff()
      .then(r => doMoreStuff())
      .then(r => push('/newPath')) // if actions succeeded, change route
      .catch(e => console.warn('doStuff() or doMoreStuff failed'));
    ...
  }
  ...
}

export default connect(null, { doStuff, doMoreStuff, push })(SomeComponent);
```

some actions in `./actions.js`:

```
export function doStuff() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return API.getSomeInfo()
      .then(info => dispatch({ type: 'GET_SOME_INFO', payload: info }))
  }
}

export function doMoreStuff() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return API.getSomeMoreInfo()
      .then(info => dispatch({ type: 'GET_SOME_MORE_INFO', payload: info }));
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could make a single promise that looks like this, where the redirect happens:

```
export function doAllStuff() {
  return dispatch => {
    return Promise.all(doStuff(), doAllStuff())
      .then(results => dispatch(push('/newPath')))
      .catch(e => console.warn('Not all actions were successful'))
  }
}
```

the component code that intiates it would just be

```
onClick = e => {
  ...
  doAllStuff(); // Since we caught the promise in the thunk, this will always resolve
  ...
}
```